# Problem with return type

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a classes:

```
    struct Policy_1
    {
        void signalFailure()
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    };

    struct Policy_2
    {
        void* signalFailure()
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    };

    template<class Policy>
    struct My
    {    
        template<class T>
        T* fnc(int value)
        {
            if (!value)
            {
                return Policy::signalFailure();//Here is the problem
            }
            else
            {
                return new int(value);
            }
        }

    };
```

The problem is that depending on Policy class signalFailure either throws or returns nullptr but I'm getting error from compiler (even though Policy is set that it does throw) that it cannot convert void to (T*) - depending what I've substitute for tea; Now, I do understand where the problem lies - compiler does syntax check and discovers that from this Policy, signalFailure returns void so it can't parse it even though signalFailure in practice throws.

I have two options as I see it:
a) either declare void* as a result type of signalFailure
b) declare void as a result type in fnc and move the result type to a args list of this fnc 
or
c) do some (and here is the real Q to you) macro or metaprogramming inside my fnc which would be determined at compile time (either return Policy::etc or just Policy::etc) and that I think would be the best option. Of course if someone of you has better and more elegant idea how to do it, is more than welcome to show it.

Comment: Shouldn't `signalFailure()` be static?

Comment: @sharptooth I agree, although I expect in real code he builds an exception message from the Policy_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using nullptr- which means that you must be in C++0x. In this case it is trivial to use decltype to solve this problem.

```
template<class Policy>
struct My
{
    template<typename T> struct func_helper {
         static T func() { return Policy::signalFailure(); }
    };    
    template<> struct func_helper<void> {
         static void* func() { Policy::signalFailure(); return nullptr; }
    };
    template<class T>
    T* fnc(int value)
    {
        if (!value)
        {
            return func_helper<decltype(Policy::signalFailure())>::func();
        }
        else
        {
            return new int(value); // Compile error if int* cannot be converted
                                   // to the type of the policy.
        }
    }

};
```

Edit: Hang on a second. This code is SERIOUSLY wrong. You're returning a new int(), as T*? This code doesn't need fixing, it needs the whole module ripping out.

Comment: nullptr is part of C++CLI before C++0x

Comment: but then second return will be invalid if signalFailure returns void.

Comment: thanks that works (and it's quite elegant I have to admit), would it be possible though to do it with macro? Then I would just have to write i.e. CHECK_POLICY(Policy) and after that this would expand to correct version of a code? Anyway I do accept your answer, but if you could come up with something with macro or <metaprogramming> it would be nice. And also elegant I think. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @There: This is template metaprogramming. You don't have to do anything with it, just call it. You don't need to write CHECK_POLICY every time, it's just once.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be shocked if the throwing policy did have a return value, though unused, and that's probably what I would do. However, if you wan't to avoid `void *`, you could as well make the `signalFailure` methods template and call `Policy::signalFailure<T>()` from fnc (thus allowing the `signalFailure` methods to returned a more strongly typed `T *`).

On a side note, the `signalFailure` methods should either be static, or `My` should privately inherit from your Policy class.